# What is the best thing to be logging in a Actors preRestart hook?

Tags: scala, akka

What methods on the reason and message should be used in logging?

Any best practice in the preRestart?

```
override def preRestart(reason: Throwable, message: Option[Any]): Unit = {
    log.error(s"preRestart $reason $message")
}
```

Comment: timestamp ? actor's name ? Both of these will be covered by logger. But what about the error it self ? `log.error(reason, s"Restarting :: ${reason.getMessages} :: $message")`

Comment: I think the message - then you will retry or reproduce the error.